# Changed to another wi-fi network does not connect

Tags: networking, wifi

I'm always connected to a wireless network in my home from my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop (via routers)

Now I am in another place where there's an iMac sharing internet connection.

My phone and other's, and a Windows laptop are connect to that network but I cannot from this laptop.

I've created a new DHCP connection with the correct SSID and left other default settings, same as the home connection.

ifconfig displays info about eth0, lo and wlan0.

Network manager doesn't recognize wlan0.

"Network is unreachable" What can I do to get connected to that network?

**Edit: I finally solved replacing Network Manager by Wicd**

Comment: I made some corrections. It wasn't 'from' iMac, it is 'to' Imac

Comment: Still a bit broad, but much better, Thanks